# Infinite sum, sequence and series, limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I am unable to crack the following question on sum of sequence and series

your help is very much appreciated..thanks

$\sum_\limits{i\geq 1} i^2x^i$

Comment: Try differentiating the g.p. twice

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking about the radius of convergence?

Comment: I am trying to find the sum of this infinite series

Answer (score 2):

You could write $i^2=i(i-1)+i$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2x^i=\sum_{i=1}^n i(i-1)x^i+\sum_{i=1}^n ix^i=x^2\sum_{i=1}^n i(i-1)x^{i-2}+x\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}$$ Now $$\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x^i\Big)$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n i(i-1)x^{i-2}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x^i\Big)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$x^k\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(\sum_{i\ge 0}x^i\right)=\sum_{i\ge k}i\cdot(i-1)\cdots(i-k)x^{i}\quad \forall k\ge 1$$